# CNAME record setting for google apps in BIND9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, cname-record

I need to reset the admin account and password for the google apps control panel because the old admin is virtually not available . In order to verify the ownership, CNAME record need to edited as per google's suggestion.  I am using BIND9 without front end .

i edited the dns  db file  like this

google123eeeee11.mydomain.com. IN  CNAME  google.com.  but after restarting the bind9, when diging the dns ,this change is not visible
( dig dns.mydomain.com )

should i need to edit /etc/named.conf ????  any help???

Comment: Are you actually hosting your own DNS?

Comment: Did you bump the serial number for the change?

Answer (score 1):

The CNAME [entry](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=47283) should be ghs.google.com & not just google.com. Also change the serial like Chris S suggested above.